# WordPress Categories Not Picking Up CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to style my category list for my layout, but for some reason, the list wordpress generates is not picking up my CSS.

Here's the relevent code:

CSS:

```
.post-categories ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.post-categories ul li {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(253,22,66);
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    color: rgb(253,22,66);
}
```

Wordpress PHP:

```
<?php echo get_the_category_list(); ?>
```

Which generates:

```
<ul class="post-categories">
    <li><a href="http://noellesnotes.com/category/music/" title="View all posts in Music" rel="category tag">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://noellesnotes.com/category/thoughts/" title="View all posts in Thoughts" rel="category tag">Thoughts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were selecting a `ul` that is a descendant of `.post-categories`. Instead of using `.post-categories ul`, you would use `ul.post-categories`, which selects a `ul` element with class `.post-categories`. This works for the given HTML structure.

Updated CSS - [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8GTSE/)

```
ul.post-categories {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    display: inline;
}

ul.post-categories li {
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(253,22,66);
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    color: rgb(253,22,66);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I wasn;t aware of that distinction. This will help in the future!